# strtr first ocurrence stop PHP

Tags: php

I made this short code for my example. The real one is much bigger.
What I need is for this strtr to take the first occurrence and stop for performance reasons since the real one is bigger.

Currently the result is "La Libertad2" and it should be "La Libertad" and stop since it found the match and not try the rest of the options.

This would take some load off the server.

If there is another way to do it, it is welcome.

```
$citygen = "Lalibertad";
$transformarciudades = array("Sanmartin" => "San Martín", "Lalibertad" => "La Libertad", "Lalibertad" => "La Libertad2");
$citygen = strtr($citygen,$transformarciudades);
echo $citygen; //result La Libertad2
```

Comment: If you have an array with repeated keys, the later value will replace earlier values. 
For example: `var_dump(array("A" => "Apple", "A" => "Ant", "A" => "Aeroplane"));` results in `array(1) { ["A"]=> string(9) "Aeroplane" }`

Comment: I know that. I put it on purpose what I need is to stop at the first value found and stop.

Comment: Since the php code I have is much larger and for server performance I need it to stop at the first value found.

Comment: By the time you reach `strstr($citygen, $transformarciudades);`, the `$transformarciudades` already lost the duplicated keys. You need to handle it from an earlier part of the code.

Comment: The problem is not really with `strstr`, but rather with your use of `array(...)`, because `array(...)` won't stop replacing the old value when a key is duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea, instead of using `strtr`, loop over the replacements, check for the existence of a match string, and if found, replace it, and break out of the loop.

```
<?php

$citygen = "Once in Lalibertad, always in Lalibertad";
$transformarciudades = array("Sanmartin" => "San Martín", "Lalibertad" => "La Libertad");

foreach($transformarciudades as $t => $v) {
    if (($p = strpos($citygen, $t)) !== false) {
        $citygen = substr($citygen, 0, $p) . $v . substr($citygen, $p + strlen($t));
        break;
    }
}

echo $citygen; // Once in La Libertad, always in Lalibertad
```

I'm not sure if this is quite what you're after, but you can modify the algorithm to replicate `strtr` without continuing to search for matches.

You might want to sort `$transformarciudades` in some other way before looping over it, but this should work.

Comment: It happens that in the array I have several repeated keys and I need it to stop at the first one and stop at the first result.

In $transformcities you remove the repeated value.
But if we put it the result is the same as my example :(

Comment: As mentioned in the comment, an array cannot have repeated keys. You will need to structure the array differently, and also use something other than `strtr` if you want it to stop at the first match.

Comment: An array of arrays with a single key => replacement could work. Like: `$transformarciudades = [ [ 'key' => 'value' ], [ 'key' => 'value 2' ], [ 'key2' => 'value 3' ] ];`

Comment: If you have an example like `$var = array(); $var['A'] = 'Apple'; $var['A'] = 'Ant'; $var['A'] = 'Aeroplane';` AND you want to change it so that it only holds the earliest value, then you should prevent the last two assignments from happening.